# Regular Expression for checking at least one alphabet or number

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regular expression that checks if a string contains only the allowed characters. The allowed characters are alphanumeric and the special characters `(),#\/\-`. I used this expression, and it is working fine.

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9 .(),#\/\-]*)+$/
```

Now I don't want the string to start with space or any disallowed characters, but it can have space in the middle. Also, the string may not consist of only special characters; it should have at least one alphanumeric character.

Can someone help me understand how to adapt the regex I am using to check these additional constraints?

Answer (score 1):

```
 ^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])([A-Za-z0-9 .(),#\/-]*)+$
```

This should do it.

Comment: regex101.com says you have an "unescaped delimiter."

Comment: @RobertHarvey it soesnt

Comment: You need to escape / So it become 
^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])([A-Za-z0-9 .(),#\/-]*)+$